# Update text field only if new value is not empty or null

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table `supportContacts`  I have a field called `comments`. I am trying to run an sql query that updates/appends new comments when the field is not empty or null. This comments are essentially coming from a textbox area inside a form, that when the user submits if empty the query should not update the field in the DB. The query below is giving me an error.  [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14c69/1)

```
UPDATE supportContacts SET IF(comments = CONCAT(comments, "Append this comment") IS NOT NULL or comments = '', 'empty', comments) WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: Why do you need to test this? If you concatenate an empty string, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the condition in the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE supportContacts
    SET Comments = CONCAT(comments, 'Append this comment')
    WHERE id = 1 and Comments is not null and Comments <> '';
```

EDIT:

You can test for the appended value being NULL or empty as well:

```
UPDATE supportContacts
    SET Comments = CONCAT(comments, @AppendComments)
    WHERE id = 1 and Comments is not null and Comments <> '' and
          @AppendComments is not null and AppendComments <> '';
```

But I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE supportContacts
    SET Comments = CONCAT(coalesce(comments, ''), @AppendComments)
    WHERE id = 1 and @AppendComments is not null ;
```

This will do nothing if the new comments are empty.  It will append new comments even when the existing ones are empty.

Comment: He wants to test the **new** value, you're testing the **old** value.

Comment: I tested this out but nothing gets updated on the query.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student . . . There was an extra condition in the last query specifying that the existing `comments` could not be `NULL` or empty.  Try without that condition.